# Front page displaying a static page , but is redirected

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Few hours ago , by curiosity I had made a big mistake with URL of my website. 
I have change it from Setting -> General Settings . I've changed the WordPress URL www.example.com and Site Address www.example.com , both , to www.example.com/wp .

I've fixed that problem , going into the database and changing wpck_options. All god, i've write my website url and when it enter to my website, surprise ....

**www.example.com/wp**

I've tried to modify the front page displays to a static page - with a selected front page and posts page ... nothing , just redirecting me to www.example.com/wp.

I'm exhausted, maybe someon who faced the same crazy issue, can help me ...

Comment: Have you delete your .htaccess and recreated it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so simple .. I had to clear my Cache from browser .  Hope that it will be helpfuly for someone else .

Learning from this :

From wordpress settings - General : 
 - Don't change wordPress Address(URL) 
 - Site Address(URL) 
-Change it only if you know what are you doing !

Solve: If you change it, go in your Cpanel, access your phpmysqladmin , and into your website database, find wpck_options: and modify siteurl and home from there

After this, clear your Chache and reload your page